# Is there a way to return the top or second parent element of a specified element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the top parent element (section) of a `myLI` id.

My HTML code is:

```
<section>
    <div>
        <ul>
          <li id="myLI">Coffee</li>
          <li>Tea</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</section>
```

My code is:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myLI").parentElement.nodeName;
```

My code returns `UL` but I would like for it to return `section`.

Comment: How do you know that `<section>` is the top? Why isn't the parent of `<section>` the top, or the grandparent, or...?  How are you determining top?

Comment: When you do want this to happen? If it is upon the clicking (or some other event associated with the `li`), you could just hook the event to the `section` in the first place.

Comment: @JonathanM I know that the section is the top because I would like to go two elements up

Comment: @ScottMarcus I will probably have it execute when a user clicks a radio button or on some type of click.

Comment: @Mariton But two elements up is the `div`, not the `section`?

Comment: @Bergi My mistake. Three elements up is the section element

Comment: If it's always just three elements up, `li.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement` it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to target the parent by tagName you could use **[`.closest(selector);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)** like :

```
var x = document.getElementById("myLI").closest('section');
```

**NOTE :** Take a look to the *Browser compatibility* section.

Hope this helps.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myLI").closest('section');

console.log(x.tagName);
```

```html
<section>
    <div>
        <ul>
          <li id="myLI">Coffee</li>
          <li>Tea</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var topParent = document.getElementById("myLI");
while( topParent.parentElement.nodeName != 'BODY' ){ 
  topParent = topParent.parentElement;
  }
  console.log( topParent.nodeName );
```

```html
<section>
    <div>
        <ul>
          <li id="myLI">Coffee</li>
          <li>Tea</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</section>
```

So I'm assuming you want the element right before the 'BODY' element?

Comment: Yes, before the body element

Comment: So does this do what you want? or not enough? this code makes no assumption that the top most parent is a `<section>`

Comment: Yes this is one solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

*"I will probably have it execute when a user clicks a radio button or on some type of click."*

Then just set up the click event on the section elements:

```js
var sections = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("section"));

sections.forEach(function(section){
  section.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(this.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<section id="one">
    <div>
        <ul>
          <li id="myLI">Coffee</li>
          <li>Tea</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="two">
    <div>
        <ul>
          <li id="myLI">Coffee</li>
          <li>Tea</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="three">
    <div>
        <ul>
          <li id="myLI">Coffee</li>
          <li>Tea</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```